# Maximum call stack size exceeded when changing a class - Bootstrap, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, jqbootstrapvalidation

I'm using jQuery 2.1.1, jQuery UI 1.11, Bootstrap 3.2, Fuel UX 2.3 (for the form wizard only) and BootstrapValidator v0.5.1-dev.

I have a huge bootstrapped form in a Fuel UX Wizard, with BootstrapValidator validation, along with a ton of jQuery for events and stuff(the total page is 1900 lines, that's why i haven't provided any code).

I had a div with class col-xs-8 around all of my form, everything was working fine. Then i changed it to class="container" (only change in the code, played it a couple of times back and forth), and now Chrome's console says :

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Why?

I have checked the call stack, there's nothing but jQuery functions there(so it shouldn't be something i or the BootstrapValidator has launched, should it?).

I have another page, with the same enviorenement, similar size and similar code - there the change from .col-xs-8 to .container went without issues.

Update: I discovered that if i leave the main div without a class, i also get the RangeError. Sooo here's my JS https://gist.github.com/sofixa/be2e575cf8a198c1cf89

Comment: " there's nothing but jQuery functions there", that is what gives the error.

Comment: What i meant was functions called by jQuery itself, nothing written by me.

Comment: Post any code you have written yourself; did you write any javascript?

Comment: There's plenty of JS(jQuery to be precise), a few hundred lines, but the problem isn't in any of that  i didn't have any problems until i changed the main div's class to container. Even now, if i change it back to col-xs-8, it works just fine.

Comment: On the other hand, without any class on the main div, i still get the error. So somehow the col-xs-something Bootstrap class was stoping the stack overflow.

Comment: I've edited the post with a link towards all of my JS code

Comment: From the error within jquery, follow the stack trace until it reaches your code. If it never reaches your code, what does it go to that isn't jquery core?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your form is NOT structured by Bootstrap classes (the element containing field and associated label does NOT have form-group class), you will see the error :

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Reference : [Maximum call stack size exceeded error warning](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/getting-started/#writing-form) in the official docs.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. But the adding the col-xs-8 class to the container eliminated that problem, which is a bit weird, probably it is unexpected to do so

Comment: It's not just `col-xs-?`, it's for all `col-?-?`, BootstrapValidator use these classes + `form-group` to get the field parent in order to place the error message. So this will cause an infinite loop.

Comment: One more thing, BootstraoValidator is no longer supported, you should upgrade to use FormValidation (commercial product) created by the same author of bootstrapValidator

Answer (score 0):

All fields mentioned under the `bootstrapValidator` function should have a parent with `form-group` class.

So it should be like this.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">No of bottles out for delivery</label>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" maxlength="3" name="bottles_out_for_delivery">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">No of bottles returned</label>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" maxlength="3" name="bottles_returned">
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$('#add_bulk_delivery_form').bootstrapValidator({
    fields: {
        bottles_out_for_delivery: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Bottles out for delivery field can\'t be empty'
                },
                regexp: {
                    regexp: /^[0-9]+$/,
                    message: 'Bottles out for delivery can only contan numbers'
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```